# How to better stop one promise chain and start another?

Tags: javascript, promise

If I have promise chain, and it successfully finished

```
var a = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ...
    })
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
    .then(function(val) {
        console.log('done');
    })
```

how I should start synchronous code or another promise chain? Maybe using `window.setTimeout()`

I do not want to call synchronous code inside function in last .then() because this function will be alive till the end of synchronous code. And also I want to divide code in two parts because these parts are perform different logic.

**EDIT**

Should I do like this?

```
// this first pormise do auth work
var auth_work = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            ...
        })
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log('done');
            // when auth procedure is finised  I want to download resources 
            return download_resources();
        });
}

var download_resources = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            ...
        })
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(function(val){
            return do_actual_work();
        });

}

var do_actual_work = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            ...
        })
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(function(val) {
            ...
        });
}
var p = auth_work();
```

What if in last .then() I will be do this `window.setTimeout(1, download_resources);`

Comment: Did you try creating a new promise, like you did with the one in your example?
So: var b = new Promise(....)
 What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "*this function will be alive till the end of synchronous code*"?

Comment: `setTimeout` is not synchronous? You should promisify it, and then use it like any other promise-returning function.

Comment: do you want to call several of promise unsync, wait until it and, and then call finish? if so try [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: When and where do you want to start another promise chain? How is it related to the one you already have? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid writing your code inside that last anonymous function where you have the `console.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if in last `.then()` I will be do this `window.setTimeout(1, download_resources);`

That makes absolutely no sense, for two reasons:

- there's no point in artificially delaying anything. Your promise code is already asynchronous.
- You won't be able to return the result of `download_resources` from your promise chain

Comment: If you have an actual problem that you're trying to solve by using `setTimeout`, please state what that problem is.

Comment: No, my problem is not in using `setTimeout`, lose scope or something like that. And I don't need to return result of `download_resources`. I try to run function in async way.  I think I put function in event loop with  `setTimeout()`. Finish current promise chain. And javascript vm, call my funcion by itself.

Comment: `download_resources` *is* already asynchronous. You can just call it. You don't need a `setTimeout` for it to be asynchronous. There does not seem to be a problem.